# Flash CS4 large project can't be exported?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4

My project on flash CS4 is getting larger, the .fla file is 55 MB and the .swf is 30 MB, I am now trying to export my movie or test it, neither of that works now, I am completely unable to run my project, help!?

does flash cs4 has limits to what it can handle in one movie?
If it is a memory problem, can I increase the memory allocated for flash to run or test movie?

Comment: how about some details on what you have in that 30 megs of a swf.

Comment: "neither of that works now" ... what happens? Do you get any error messages? Does the Flash player launch? Are you running in the "Flash projector" or the browser?

Comment: My project contain lots of images and sounds, and no there is no errors at all, it might be the images files too large to be loaded..

Comment: The flash player is OK, but when I use the source file to export the movie that will be played by the Flash PLayer, the source is not able to export the .swf file... I am running in the A Flash Projector..

Comment: When did it stopped working to export it? One of your library items might be corrupt. Also, try to clear the publish cache.

Comment: OMG, that was true, There is an image file which was 1,200x1,600 found its properties read by flash as 30,000x50,000 and when I try to open it flash gives me error, I now removed and re-imported it and Wholaaa flash runs again :) , Thanks you very much...